# Youtube API - fadeIn video to div - not working in Opera 10

Tags: javascript, youtube, cross-browser, youtube-api

I'm using this code to fadeIn youtube video into #vid div when user clicks on button and automatically play it as well. It works perfectly in all browsers, but for some reason when I try clicking on the button in Opera 10.5 nothing happens. Any idea what could be wrong and how to fix it, please?

Javascript:

```
    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('vid', {
        height: '539',
        width: '958',
        videoId: 'CZ0Jorye0jU',
        events: {
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
      });
    }
    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
      if(event.data === 0) {            
        $("#vid").fadeOut(500);
      }
    }
    function startVideo() {
      $("#vid").fadeIn(2000); 
      player.playVideo();
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 160 }, 600); return false; 
    };
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:startVideo();" class="eshop index" style="width:319px; left:320px; border-right:1px solid white;">Prehrať ukážku</a>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if this would work, but instead of using the JavaScript in the href, why not add a class I.e.

```
<a class="startVideo eshop index" style="width:319px; left:320px; border-right:1px solid white;">Prehrať ukážku</a>
```

Ad then bind the startVideo() function to a click event on that.

```
$('.startVideo').click(function() { startVideo(); });
```

Like I say, I'm not sure if it would definitely work, but it's worth a shot. The other thing to test is to see if it is the startVideo that isn't firing for sure. Just stick an alert('hiya') at the beginning of the startVideo() function and click the button to check tat it's getting that far.

Hope that helps. Good luck.